Strange behaviour selecting input text on focus in Angular
I am trying to select all text when entering a input text element in angular.
It works well in most cases. But if I click a button that do not change the element value when the element has focus, the cursor is set to the place I click on the element after clicking the button.
If the value is changed by the button click, the complete input is selected as expected.
Here is code to reproduce the problem:
HTML
<input [value]="myValue" (focus)="onFocus($event)">
<button (click)="buttonClick($event)" >No change</button>
<button (click)="buttonValueChangeClick($event)" >Value Change</button>

TS
  myValue: number = 123.456;

  onFocus(event: any) {
    event.target.select();
  }
  buttonClick(event: any) {}
  
  buttonValueChangeClick(event: any) {
    this.myValue += 1.23;
  }

First click the input field to select the text. Then click the one of the button. When clicking again in the input field, after pressing the value change button, the text is selected as expected. But when clicking the other button, the the marker is set to where in the text it was clicked.

I just use: <input [value]="myValue" onfocus="this.select()">  but I see some odd behavior sometimes too.  (basically it doesn't always work, and I've never figured out why)  I think browser input controls have always been a little quirky when it comes to select, caretposition, etc...  I remember you used to have to use a small settimeout for some reason.
